# Lenovo yoga 13 Display Issue

Tags: windows-8.1, display, intel-graphics, lenovo-laptop

I can't connect Etra (Extended / Duplicate) Screen to the usb 3 docking station of Lenovo Yoga 13, Since After I upgraded to Windows 8.1.
I reinstalled Intel HD Graphics 4000 driver from Lenovo Site and the Display won't work.

help please,

Answer (score -1):

This is all you need bro, solved.

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Idea-Windows-based-Tablets-and/Yoga-13-Video/m-p/1272851#M8030

Comment: PirateHawk, please summarize the solution here in the post. Link-only answers are not preferable because the links may change or go dead. 
Leave the link in for reference, but at least copy the important parts of the solution.